# Secure Wordpress: Change admin

Tags: security

I'm sorry if this is an extremely stupid question.

I've been looking for ways how to secure my WP and a lot of websites suggest to create a new admin user account and delete the old one.
Now, if I use a different screenname as author (when writing comments etc.) - how could hackers still find out what my admin username is anyways?

I'm just wondering if this step really makes sense unless your administrator username is "admin".

Thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: Here’s my plugin solution for username: [Admin username changer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-username-changer/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, if your username isnt admin (older versions) you really dont need to do that.

What i would reccomend is for you to install 2-3 plugins
ordered here by their importance:

1. [wordpress firewall 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-firewall-2/)
2. [Limit Login attempts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/)
3. [Wp Security Scan](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/)

Wordpress Firewall should stop must hack attempts directly on your site, Limit login should end any change of a brute login attemp and wp security should show you any loop holes in your file permission structure and othere stuff...

.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your comment. Wow, that's a lot of plugins to install. I prefer having almost no plugins installed, but I will have a look at it :)

Comment: Great! if you pick one i would take wordpress firewall or at least the first 2 ones :) - good luck

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still waiting for other people to post as I'm always glad to get good tips how to make Wordpress more secure anyways, but for now I'm definitely marking your answer as accepted!! :D

Comment: +1 A good list of plug-ins. I would add that it's advisable to publish content under a different name to the account that has admin access (*whether or not its called 'admin'*). Author pages reveal the username, and could lead to brute force attacks. (See [this discussion](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-July/043638.html) on wp-hackers)